# React - Como comunicar componente hijo con el padre, en una llamada Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Tengo un componente llamado **app** que se encarga de renderizar una barra de menú con opciones. Una de las opciones es el **login**.

Cuando el usuario se loguea correctamente via petición con axios, **me interesa retornar una variable booleana que indique que el login es exitoso**. Siguiendo el siguiente tutorial: [enlace](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17) pude implementar el siguiete code que adjunto.

**El problema es que no esta ejecutando el metodo en el padre**

Se implemento el siguiente componente padre app:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = ({
     isUserLogin: false
  })

  this.myCallback = this.myCallback.bind(this);
 }

 //funcion ques se ejecutaria cuando se retornen los datos
 myCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
  //  [...we will use the dataFromChild here...]
  alert('soy el padre' + dataFromChild);
 }

 // ref: https://gist.github.com/darklilium/183ce1405788f2aef7e8
 render() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <>
          { (this.state.isLoggedIn) ? null : <NavBar /> }
          {/* <NavBar /> */}
            <div className="container">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          <PiePagina />
        </>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

En su hijo llamado **Login** tengo implementado la siguiente logica (copio lo principal para que no sea extenso):

```
class Login extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
        username:'',
        password:'',
        errors: {},
        errorApi: ''
    })

    this.cambioUsername = this.cambioUsername.bind(this);
    this.cambioPassword = this.cambioPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit   = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 
    this.consumirApiLogin = this.consumirApiLogin.bind(this);
    this.validarFormulario = this.validarFormulario.bind(this);
}
consumirApiLogin() {
    const payload={
        "_username":this.state.username,
        "_password":this.state.password,
    }
    axios.post(API_LOGIN, payload)
        .then(response => {
            // console.log(response.data.token);
            // this.setState({errorApi: response.data})
            // console.log(this.state.errorApi);
            sessionStorage.setItem('AccessToken', response.data.token);
            // INTENTO LLAMAR AL METODO DEL PADRE, PERO NO EJECUTA NADA
            // TAMPOCO GENERA UN ERROR EN LA CONSOLA
            this.props.callbackFromParent('hijo');
        })
        .catch(e => {
            if(e.response)
            {
                let error = '';
                error = e.response.data.message;
                this.setState({errorApi: error});
            }
        });
}
```

Si me pueden orientar, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la declaración de tus rutas no pasas bien las props al componente hijo.

Si quieres pasar datos del padre al hijo en un componente enrutado puedes usar la prop [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) que recibe una función en línea y devuelve el componente a renderizar con las props que indiques.

También puedes pasar una función en línea a la prop [component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component) de `<Route />` pero no es recomendable tal como pone en la documentación, ya que crearía un componente wrapper sobre el componente a renderizar y se tendrian que ejectuar los método montaje y desmontaje.

Por eso recomiendan, usar la prop `render` que devuelve el componente a renderizar y no se crea un componente wrapper innecesario tal como se haría en la prop `component`.

```
 <Route 
    exact 
    path="/login" 
    render={() => <Login callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}/>} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es por que le estas pasando la función a Route y no a Login tienes 2 soluciones para solucionar esto:

1.- The Best:

```
<Route exact path="/login" render={() => <Login callbackFromParent={this.myCallback} />}/>
```

2.-

```
<Route exact path="/login">
    <Login callbackFromParent={this.myCallback} />
</Route>
```

De esta forma el método llega a Login y se puede ejecutar correctamente.